# Help me clean up tags for the Selenium framework

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

With over 6500 rep on SO (most of it from Selenium-related answers), I thought I'd be able to suggest some of the needed synonyms / changes to tags around the [Selenium framework](http://seleniumhq.org/). However, the system doesn't seem to like me:

> Failed to propose synonym: Version specific synonyms can only be
>   created by moderators

Fair enough. But now I need a little bit of your help. It's not that bad, it's just a little messy.

---

The Selenium framework (which enables you to programatically control any browser, mostly used for web application front-end testing) consists of several projects:

- Selenium RC, now officially deprecated, but still heavily in use
- Selenium IDE, a Firefox add-on, a simple test recording tool backed by Selenium RC
- Selenium WebDriver (formerly known as Selenium 2), the right way to go these days
- Selenium Grid, a tool for running the tests in parallel among several computers

That said, this is the current tagging situation:

- [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) is a general tag usually used on any Selenium-related problem. That's okay, I guess.
- [selenium-rc](/questions/tagged/selenium-rc) is okay.
- [selenium-ide](/questions/tagged/selenium-ide) is okay.
- [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) is okay.
- [selenium-grid](/questions/tagged/selenium-grid) is okay.
- [selenium2](/questions/tagged/selenium2) is an old and unuseful way to name the project ([or, more specifically, the project version](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/a-smattering-of-selenium-53/)). There have been a lot of confusion about the project names and numbers etc., but the developers made themselves very clear and the name "Selenium 2" is used less and less frequently. This should be a synonym for [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) as that's the right name.
- [webdriver](/questions/tagged/webdriver) should be a synonym for [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver), too. [At least until there's any other implementation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webdriver-20120710/).
- [selenium-xpath](/questions/tagged/selenium-xpath) is just plain wrong, this should be simply [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath). Do you have any tools for mass retag, or should I do it carefully and manually for every question? There's not that many.
- [selenium-server](/questions/tagged/selenium-server) has 8 questions asked. From the five of them I can see, two are mistagged (will repair tomorrow), the rest could be possibly retagged to [selenium-rc](/questions/tagged/selenium-rc). The "server" is a part of Selenium implementation everyone on RC had to go through, it's not a standalone part of Selenium that would need its own tag and would have its own audience. *I think.*
- [selenium-fitnesse-bridge](/questions/tagged/selenium-fitnesse-bridge) is okay.
- [selenium-rails](/questions/tagged/selenium-rails) should be probably just [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) and some subset of the valid tags above, there's no special version for Ruby-on-rails that would make it special.
- [selenium-firefoxdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-firefoxdriver) and [selenium-chromedriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-chromedriver) I'm not sure about these. FirefoxDriver and ChromeDriver are specific WebDriver implementations (every browser has one). [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox)/[google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) should probably be more than good enough. Considering also the very small amount of people using Selenium, any further fragmentation is a Bad Thing™ imho.

---

Wow, this is long. What can I do to make this happen?

Comment: I do not use Selenium, but as someone who often answers in [css-selectors] which it makes use of, some of my answers are to questions with Selenium tags as well, and I come across related tags on occasion. These don't look difficult - I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn To be honest, I was kind of hoping to bump into you here :). Also, I feel ashamed of the typos in the question - too tired to think. If there's anything I could do to make the job done, please don't hesitate to tell me. I'll gladly help in a couple of hours.

Comment: I would re-tag things out of [tag:webdriver], but not synonym it. At some point there may be other implementations, and for right now it seems like it would be better to encourage people to tag with [tag:selenium-webdriver] and [tag:watir] or some other front-ending bits.

Comment: Re: [tag:selenium], this strikes me the same way [tag:vmware] and [tag:microsoft] did on Server Fault ("Which of their many products do you mean?") -- Is there any reason you wouldn't want to force the more specific `selenium-product` tags?

Comment: I've retagged all [selenium-xpath] questions to [xpath], and done away with [selenium-rails] as well. Does "Selenium standalone server" always refer to Selenium RC?

Comment: @voretaq7 As of [webdriver], I completely agree. If all `webdriver` questions are retagged as `selenium-webdriver` and the tag is removed as for now, all people would use `selenium-webdriver` by default. Sure, somebody may try to recreate it, but we'll be watching :).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn and @voretaq7 (even though he won't be  notified): For `selenium` tag, I'm not sure. Voretaq7 is right about that the tag is mostly redundant on most questions, one of the existing ones are enough. That said, it makes tracking of all the selenium tags much easier if every single one of them is tagged with it. It would be nice if SO offered something like "tag families". How is this handled in the general case on SO?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I'll take a deep look tomorrow and report back.

Comment: @Slanec: Any updates on this? At least we can get [selenium2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium2) merged into [selenium-webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) now, looks like [selenium2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium2) is getting less active nowadays.

Comment: Might be revisiting this based on Yi Zeng's comment - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215586/wrong-tag-synonym-webdriver-selenium

Comment: Other WebDriver implementations seem to be making appearances now. So... really unsure about [webdriver] to [selenium-webdriver].

Comment: [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) is one example of a WebDriver implementation not provided by the Selenium project

Comment: And [WebdriverJS](http://webdriver.io/) is an example of a WebDriver language binding not provided by the selenium project.