# Wrong tag synonym: webdriver -> selenium

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

I noticed that [webdriver](/questions/tagged/webdriver) tag has been merged into [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium). This is not correct.

[Help me clean up tags for the Selenium framework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166995/220697) has explained it well, but no one has taken any correct actions yet (but somehow a wrong move is made).

Basically, [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) is a general tag for [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver), [selenium-rc](/questions/tagged/selenium-rc), [selenium-ide](/questions/tagged/selenium-ide) and more. [WebDriver](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webdriver-20120710/) is some kind of API and Selenium WebDriver implements it. On the other hand, Selenium is a web automation tool, which includes Selenium IDE, Selenium RC and Selenium WebDriver.

[image]

**Suggestions:**

- Separate [webdriver](/questions/tagged/webdriver) out of  [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium).
- Merge [selenium2](/questions/tagged/selenium2), [webdriver](/questions/tagged/webdriver) into [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver). (This involves version specific merging, so most users like myself are not privileged to suggest it).

**EDIT:**

Still no actions are taken after posting this. Recently, even [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) has been merged into [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium). Personally I think this is wrong at the moment (Selenium is going release new version soon though). Even if this is correct direction, then we definitely also need to merge selenium2 into them to keep consistency.

Comment: What do you suggest as the corrective action?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Merge `selenium2` into `selenium-webdriver`, separate `webdriver` out of `selenium`. But need more discussion on if `webdriver` needs to be merged into `selenium-webdriver` or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah I just happened to notice this while retagging some [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) questions the other day... not sure what happened there.

I disassociated the two tags from [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) and made [selenium2](/questions/tagged/selenium2) and [webdriver](/questions/tagged/webdriver) synonyms of [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver). I'll monitor the tags for a while and see what happens.

Actually, I'm wondering if [webdriver](/questions/tagged/webdriver) is appropriate as a synonym of [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver). [WebDriver](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver) is a standard of which Selenium just happens to have the most well-known implementation. Most people using [webdriver](/questions/tagged/webdriver) are probably asking about Selenium and therefore probably have either [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) or [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) in their question already anyway. I'll remove the synonym for now; questions should be unaffected other than how the tag is displayed. I'll have to see if any concrete retags should be done after the fact — there is *a lot* of them after all.

Comment: Thanks, finally had it sorted. Also, someone started adding [tag:selenium-webdriver-c#] and removing [tag:selenium-webdriver] + [tag:c#]. I'm not sure which way makes more sense to you?

Comment: Pretty sure [selenium-webdriver] and [c#] will suffice, or even without [c#] if the question doesn't involve the use of C#.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer the same. Could you please do something about it? People will start clicking [tag:selenium-webdriver-c#] and [tag:selenium-webdriver-java], because they show up in the drop down automatically. In the future, we might also see [selenium-webdriver-ruby], [selenium-webdriver-python], [selenium-webdriver-php], etc. That'd be a disaster.

Comment: Yeah I'm retagging all of them right now. I even found some questions that had the wrong language tag. Clearly having the language after the library in the tag name isn't helping matters, although someone who I would have expected to know better seems to have be the one who started it.

Comment: I saw [Salvador Dali](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1090562/salvador-dali) has been doing it, who isn't anywhere in selenium top-answerers. I tried to rollback some of them, then decided to get you to help out. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your time too.